# Why inline style sheet make Stage area black at startup in JavaFx?

Tags: css, javafx

I'm using `inline style` for `buttons` and `textfield` but when I run project `stage` area splash black for few seconds and then load content.

Why it does happen?

```
<Button layoutX="700.0" layoutY="105.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="100.0" style="-fx-background-radius: 101000;" text="Delete">
     <graphic>
        <FontAwesomeIconView glyphName="TRASH_ALT" size="24" />
     </graphic></Button>
```

Comment: Is your `Button` larger than 202000 x 202000 pixels of why do you choose such a large background radius?

Comment: Oh what value I should use then?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve when setting this css property? Usually you choose the horizontal/vertical radii at most half as large as the widht/height of the region.

Comment: I want to make button corners round.

Comment: `Button` does not achieve its look using a border. Multiple backgrounds are stacked on top of each other. Not sure, if this is an up to date version of `modena.css` (the stylesheet responsible for the default style), but the relevant css rule looks like this or similar: https://gist.github.com/maxd/63691840fc372f22f470#file-modena-css-L419 The number of background fills depends on the state of the button (focused, non-focused ect.); for this reason I strongly recommend using a css stylesheet instead of inline css